# Plot rad(sqrt(3*sin(deg(abs(2*\x)))) with tikz where it reaches the x-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote, trignometry

I am trying to plot **sqrt(3*sin|2x|)** which should look like the figure below and have several other similar plots to do as well, but mine does not reach the x-axis. The plot works out well until I add the sqrt to the function.

[image: What it should look like]

This is my code and result:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
domain=-10:10,
xmin=-5, xmax=5,
samples=1000,
axis lines=center,
xtick distance=1.5,
ytick=\empty,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
xtick={-4.5,-3,-1.5,1.5,3,4.5},xticklabels={$-\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$-\pi$,$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\frac{\pi} 
{2}$,$\pi$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$}
]
\addplot[mark=none, black] {rad(sqrt(3*sin(deg(abs(2*\x)))))};
\addplot[mark=none, black] {rad(-sqrt(3*sin(deg(abs(2*\x)))))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: What it comes out as]

I have tried to fix the issue by increasing my samples, but I went up to 10000 to no avail.  It gets closer to the x-axis, but does not connect with it and the runtime causes it to time out with higher samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your scale, so I changed a few things there. I think the problem is the number of samples, as you expected. The following code works fine for me, <strike>but if I put less than 4000 samples</strike>, but if I put an even number of samples, I can see a gap when the function takes the value zero. <strike>However, it takes some time to compile.</strike>

Another couple of things. I divided the plot into several parts to avoid sine negative values and I think you don't need `rad` in the `addplot`.

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage   {pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset  {compat=1.17}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      [
        domain=-2:2,
        xmin=-2, xmax=2,
        ymin=-2.5, ymax=2.5,
        samples=101,
        axis lines=center,
        ytick=\empty,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        xtick={-1.5,-1,...,1.5},
        xticklabels={$-\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$-\pi$,$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\frac{3\pi}{2}$}
      ] 
      \foreach\i in{-1.5,-0.5,0,1}
      {
        \addplot[mark=none, red, domain=\i:\i+0.5]  {sqrt(3*sin(deg(abs(2*pi*x))))};
        \addplot[mark=none, red, domain=\i:\i+0.5] {-sqrt(3*sin(deg(abs(2*pi*x))))};
      }
      \addplot[mark=none, red] coordinates {(1.25,2)} node {$y^2=3\sin|2x|$};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

This is how it looks:
[image]

**EDIT1**: I removed the package `ifthen` which is not needed (a copy-paste mistake).

**EDIT2**: I changed the number of samples. Works with only 101, but it has to be an odd number. Why? No idea.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am having a timeout issue with Overleaf though.  Can you suggest an offline editor that I can use which compiles with LuaLatex (the work I am doing requires the compiler to be set up in this way)

Comment: Texmaker can do that. It's my default editor but I don't normally use LuaLaTeX, just PdfLaTeX. I just tried LuaLaTeX in Texmaker and there is another problem: you need even more samples (I don't know why).

Comment: I did a couple more tests. With PdfLaTeX the plot looks good with just 101 samples. But with 100 or 102 I still see a little gap. I think the issue is related to even/odd numbers. This is not working in LuaLaTeX though.